# Proper site project structure when project under development

Tags: django, git, apache, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying at first time develop site on my own, and don't have any real experience, but have a bit of frameworks and technologies in use. At the current moment I am using **django** which runs under local **apache** server. And for the front-end part I am using **bootstrap** sources with **less**. And I have to use **git**. So project folder will contain a lot of that releases site mustn't.

The apache root directory, default one that was offered, is *var/www/html/bestsite*. It is not so convenient in use, because it requires root user, so every editor have to be run under root user.

Well next logical step is reconfig apache to use other path, let's say *home/user/projects/bestsite*, but it again here I will have a lot of unnecessary for releases site mustn't.
I can write some script or use Grunt to copy only bestsite's content back into *var/www/html/bestsite*, but I have doubts about rationality of this solution.

Finally the question is how it should be? How do you organize your projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For development don't use Apache. use the built-in development server. You can run it with `python manage.py runserver`. When it comes to less or sass I would recommend to use [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor). It integrates well with the django development server where it generates your css on the fly.

I would suggest to use a [vagrant box](https://www.vagrantup.com/) for development. So you can develop on a production like system. [It's also possible to spin up Amazon EC2 instances with vagrant](http://www.iheavy.com/2014/01/16/how-to-deploy-on-amazon-ec2-with-vagrant/).

You are free in sense of project structure if the configuration is right. It depends heavily on the size of your project. For small projects the default structure fits well. I personally wrap this django-project folder with a folder where git, configs, etc. find there place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why I mustn’t use Apache when site in developing? Is there any explanations for this? Will it be better to develop using built-in django development server, and then, when it ready, test it by placing site on local Apache server?

Comment: when you use the built-in development server you don't have to call `collectstatic` everytime  you change something and you can see log output. Also it's possible to set some breakpoint with pdb.